# Activity is destroyed on intent creation

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an application implementing a bar code scanner.
Several values are gathered and displayed in the same Activity. Everytime the user wants to get a new value, he calls an Intent on a another application in the device which handles the bar code scanning part, and returns a String containing the actual value held by the bar code.
In the end, mutliple values from multiple scans are meant to be displayed in the same Activity.

It works perfectly on two different devices (Nexus 7 on Android 4.4.2, Vuzix M100 on Android 4.0.4).
On those two, it goes well and on second intent return, my previous values are still stored in the Activity.
But on the Alcatel One Touch Mini s 2 (Android 4.3), everytime I come back to the first activity, it goes through the onCreate method of the relevant Activity and erases the previous scan values stored in global Activity variables.

I have searched over the web but I couldn't manage to find any clue.**Why does only one phone out of three erases the Activity for every intent created, and how can I prevent it?**

It doesn't seem to be a hardware ressource problem (as said in the doc, Paused intents can be destroyed to free memory) because the problematic device is almost the most powerful.

Comment: Even though this device is "almost the most powerful", I assume that Android just destroys your activity to free up resources. Do you save your activity state? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Comment: No I didn't, but I'll surely try that. What would be the advantage of doing that instead of saving the data in a static class or singleton? I guess you also store all the properties of the Views, color, focus, etc..

Comment: @helleye It worked perfectly with the onSaveInstanceState(), thank you very much!
You should maybe write it in an answer so it could help others eventually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be prepared for cases when your activity gets destroyed, and later recreated. For this Android calls onSaveInstanceState() where you can store the information that you need in the Bundle provided. Then when the activity is recreated, onCreate() will be called with this Bundle passed as a parameter, so you can read your data from it. You can read more about this here => [Saving Activity State](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState)

Answer (score 0):

"everytime I come back to the first activity, it goes through the onCreate method of the relevant Activity and erases the previous scan values stored in global Activity variables" --> could you store them in a shared preference that you read each time in onCreate?

Comment: That's what I thought I'll do (but I'm still hesitating between a singleton and a "basic" static class) but i was quite surprise and curious about the fact that it work on two devices and not on the third one.

Comment: Read this about restoring activity state http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Also, read this about shared preferences, as you seem confused between shared preferences and in memory saving of data in a static class or singleton http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that and I'll be right back.

Comment: I finally used a savedInstanceState, which works well. Shared Preferences seems to be a bit "too much" for me as I don't want to save the data after the user exits the application. But I learned something, so thanks anyway :)